# Rename-Item only changing it to the last two characters

Tags: powershell

How can I make the rename-Item change the document to display all of the characters from what I get from Get-Content?

the get-content I use currently has 76 characters (no spaces)

Below is the txt file that has been chnaged but is only displaying the last two characters.

[image]

Below is the code I am using,

```
$test = (Get-Content C:\test\94951595.wav.txt)[6,7,4] -join
$test = $test -Replace " ",""
$test = (72Charcters ending in 02)
Rename-Item C:\Test\94951595.wav.txt -NewName C:\Test\$test
```

I will not be sharing the output of the $test - due to confidentiality.

Example though
test123456789test23456789test3456789test456789test5679test6789test789test:02

Comment: You need to tell us what the value of `$test` is after the second line has been executed I think

Comment: Have you validated that the example `$test` value you have given us reproduces the problem? There is no point just giving us 72 characters if it doesn't

Comment: Also, ```$test = (Get-Content C:\test\94951595.wav.txt)[6,7,4] -join``` isn't valid powershell syntax - you need to provide a string to use as the join value - e.g. ```@("aaa", "bbb", "ccc") -join ""```, **or** put the values on the right-hand side - e.g. ```-join @("aaa", "bbb", "ccc")``` - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_join?view=powershell-7.3#syntax

Comment: Thank you all for your help and comments, 

I have figured it out ":" is not permitted in a name. Apologies for the silly question. just started learning PowerShell today :) 

Have a great day all.

Comment: @Steve - glad you've found a fix, but when you say "':' is not permitted in a name", what sort of name do you mean? If it's a variable name it's **possible** but very unusual, and you have to surround the name with ```${...}``` to reference it - e.g. ```${aaa.bbb} = "xyz"; write-host ${aaa.bbb}```, and filenames definitely allow "." in them.

Comment: @mclayton - they say colon not period

Comment: @MartinSmith - oops - I misread it with the quotes around it :-).